# Reading from and writing to registers of an IMU via UART

Tags: c, linux, uart

I have an IMU that has a UART interface. The manufacturer has provided a Windows based program that get all the data from the IMU and displays it in real time. (The device is connected to the PC via the USB). I need to write my own software that does this in order to integrate it into my project.

The datasheet/manual for the IMU gives all details about which registers have to be written to and read from (issue commands and read responses) in order to get the IMU data. My question is, how do I implement this in C under Linux?

The closest information I found out was [this one](https://sysplay.in/blog/linux-device-drivers/2013/09/accessing-x86-specific-io-mapped-hardware-in-linux/) but when compiling it it seems I need Linux kernel headers since that program uses `#include <linux/module.h>` so I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: How you would implement that under Windows, provided you have the docs? We don't have them, so we could not tell you if the direction to include `<linux/module.h>` is right one or not.

Comment: I don't know that as well. The manual only gives information about the names, addresses and functions of all registers. It doesn't tell how the software has to be written. The software that was provided is for Windows but I don't have the source code. The manual is [here](http://global.epson.com/products_and_drivers/sensing_system/download_hidden/pdf/m-v340pd_datasheet_e_rev.20151218.pdf)

Comment: *"My question is, how do I implement this in C under Linux?"* -- You have to first determine if the command/response message protocol requires cannonical or non-canonical mode.  IOW do the commands and responses each consist of a line of ASCII text, or are they binary messages?

Comment: They are binary messages

Answer (score 1):

You need not any kernel headers to talk over a serial port with any device connected to that serial port.

You would get a 'connection' to your device by simply opening a file `/dev/ttyUSB0` with `open()` call (the actual name could be found by looking into `dmesg` for relevant device messages or by looking what device node appears under `/dev` when you plug your device into `usb` port). 
Then you would need to set the baud rate and the word format (number of bits, parity and number of stop bits). To achieve that from the user-space process you would use a set of `ioctl`s. For details read `man ioctl` and `man ioctl_list`

Comment: Since it's a tty device you should use `tcsetattr` to set the baud rate and other parameters.

Comment: @Serge, so to confirm that, I do not need to access the registers to get the sensor info, right? All that I need to do is to read from the file /dev/ttyXXX ?

Comment: When I connect the device to the USB and do cat /dev/ttyUSB0, I see nothing so I though I have to read from the registers directly. I know I am using the correct device node

Comment: Why do you expect to see something with `cat` while you do not send any command to the device?

Comment: This is just a long comment rather than a real answer to the question.

Comment: @Serge, I set the baud rate etc using the stty command: stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb and then I did cat. Is there any other command that lets us issue commands to the device?

Comment: @user1420 you can try `echo -en "blablabla" >/dev/ttyUSB0` (`-e` to enable `echo` to scan the string for escape sequences `-n` to tell the `echo` to not append `\n` (newline) char at the end). But definitely, this is not the way you should talk to the device behind the serial port.